# Atributo por $_POST perde informação

Tags: php, html, mysql

eu tenho um atributo chamado `$nomeConteudo`, que faz um select no meu banco e retorna o valor corretamente, pois através do echo eu confiro que o valor está normal.

Dentro de uma form, eu preciso enviar esse valor para meu formaction. Por ja ter o valor, eu envio ele pelo input hidden.

```
<input type="hidden" name="nomeConteudo" value=<?= $nomeConteudo ?>>
```

Acontece que quando eu recebo esse valor na minha action form:

```
$nomeConteudo = $_POST['nomeConteudo'];
```

E dou um `echo $nomeConteudo;`, a informação da mesma é reduzida para apenas a primeira frase do que eu contenho

Por exemplo: tenho atribuído o valor informatica media complexidade, ele só me retornara informatica.

Já procurei soluções e não encontrei nada satisfatório. Alguém saberia o que está acontecendo?

Segue imagens que podem ajudar no entendimento... [image: Conteudo Luiz, antes de clicar na action form (botao submeter)]

---

[image: Após submeter ao action form. Apenas Conteudo. Perdendo a informação "Luiz"]

Comment: É aconselhável você também enviar o trecho do código do formulário de envio em que está essa variável e também o trecho do código do arquivo em que você recebe essa variável.

Comment: Eu alterei para a variavel receber localmente, sem ser pelo banco o conteudo "Teste de Conteudo", e enviando para o action form ele so da o echo de "Teste"

Comment: Experimente a seguinte linha:
<input type="hidden" name="nomeConteudo" value=".$nomeConteudo." >

Comment: Não funcionou, @White. Dessa maneira ele imprime o conteudo '.$nomeConteudo.' como se fosse uma string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal descobri o problema, eu estava enviando o input desta forma:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="nomeConteudo" value=<?=$nomeConteudo;?> >
```

e o correto é desta:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="nomeConteudo" value="<?=$nomeConteudo;?>" >
```

Essas benditas aspas me deram muita dor de cabeça. Mas está ai.